# CodeIgniter calls /index.php instead of /basefolder/index.php , on Nginx?

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

I am running CodeIgniter 3.0.6 in an Nginx server and subpaths end up serving `/index.php`, rather than `/<installdir>/index.php`. So, if I ask for `/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/home/` I get served the `/index.php` page instead, rather than `/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/index.php` as expected. Note, that my CodeIgniter application will eventually reside in `/2016/`.

I suspect this is down to a misconfiguration of my Nginx install, rather than something CodeIgniter related? My Nginx install is running on Ubuntu 16.04. The contents of the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default are:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

Is there something else I should be changing?

Comment: Do you need `/index.php` or can you simply change the `try_files` default? See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: I'll try without. I was basing myself on some other examples.

Answer (score 0):

If your server has a single application with the main entry point at `/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/index.php`, you should probably set your locations like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /CodeIgniter-3.0.6/index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

That way, any URI that is not a match for a resource file or a `.php` file, will be routed to your applications default entry point `/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/index.php`.

However, if there is more than one application, such that `/index.php` and `/CodeIgniter-3.0.6/index.php` are two distinct entry points, you may want to set up locations for each application, possibly like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
location /CodeIgniter-3.0.6 {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /CodeIgniter-3.0.6/index.php;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

That way, only URIs that begin with `/CodeIgniter-3.0.6` will be routed to that application's default entry point.